# How do you specify an optional thousands separator in C#?

Tags: c#, format, number-formatting

I'm trying to print physical quantities from a `decimal` datatype with up to 6 decimal places.  I want the thousands separator to show up, but only for numbers that are >= 10,000 (or <= -10,000).

For instance:

- 100 -> 100
- 1000 -> 1000
- 9999 -> 9999
- 10000 -> 10,000

I've been using this format, but it's not quite right:

```
myNumber.ToString("#,##0.######");
```

Is there a trick to the format string to get the thousands separator to only show up if there are 5 or more digits to the left of the decimal place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is any special trick, you'll have to do

```
var result = myNumber >= 10000.0m || myNumber <= -10000.0m ? 
                 myNumber.ToString("#,##0.######") : 
                 myNumber.ToString("###0.######");
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think your 'd''s should be 'm''s though.

Comment: @ScottWhitlock you are right. For some reason I thought you `myNumber` was double.

Answer (score 1):

You could use myNumber.ToString("n") which should use the current culture and format appropriately

Comment: sorry, I just noticed you only wanted it to apply for numbers over 10,000. What is the reason behind that? Just curious

Comment: I'm not sure where it comes from, probably taste, but the requirements for the result is: 1000 or 10,000.  They don't want to see 1,000.

Comment: interesting.  

For ease would create an extension that uses Bala R's logic then

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'll have to do.

Comment: @AnthonyShaw: It's pretty common formatting, fe. in books, I'm just reading Windows Concurrency and they are formatting numbers like that: 5000 but 50 000. (different separator, but same rule) :).

Comment: @Ravandre - Yeah, I just asked a co-worker because I thought I was going nuts.  I'd always been taught to use this rule as far back as primary school.  It's probably a custom based on when numbers are embedded into text or paragraphs, and that's the case I'm dealing with here.  Also, I'm going to be switching it to a space separator anyway to follow the SI standard.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is anything "built in", but this is the sort of case that Iformatprovider & ICustomFormatter were designed for. See [iformatprovider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformatprovider.aspx).